# Laravel | Why is the id missing in a eloquent model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-jetstream

We are [customizing our key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#customizing-the-default-key-name) to use a unique identifier in our routing.

So this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/TEAMS/1
```

ends up like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/TEAMS/91e11f44-2d89-4b5e-83e0-5cb92d0c0ebd
```

This works great but unfortunately we're getting an error at another point.
When we create a new team, we can't access the `id` of that newly created team:

[image: dd]

You see that the `primaryKey` points at the `id`-attribute but this is missing in the `attributes`-array. So we can't access

```
$newTeam->id 
// or
$newTeam['id']
```

Currently we are fetching the team after creation with

```
$team = Team::where('identifier', $newTeam->identifier)->first();
```

but that seems to be redundant.

**Does someone know how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.**

**Edit**

This is the relevant part from the `model`

```
class Team extends JetstreamTeam
{
    use \App\Http\Traits\UsesIdentifier;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'identifier',
        'name',
        'personal_team',
    ];


    /**
     * Specify the routing key
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'identifier';
    }
}
```

Migration:

```
class CreateTeamsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('teams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('user_id')->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->boolean('personal_team');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('teams');
    }
}
```

Trait:

```
trait UsesIdentifier
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->identifier = (string) Str::uuid();
        });
    }

    public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getKeyType()
    {
        return 'string';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your model and migration here ?

Comment: Am I missing something or you don't have an `identifier` column iin your database? It is missing in the migiration

Comment: Your right.. but it is in our database, so it must be deleted by mistake. I'll check that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are insufficient information about your table's primary key, I can assume the following.

- You have mentioned that you are using custom primary key. the identifier column. So, you don't have the `id` column in your table. The default `find()` method works on the `id` field.
- To make it work with your customized `identifier` column, you have to define the primary key as below.

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'identifier';
}
```

After this, you can access model like this:

```
$team = Team::find($newTeam->identifier);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I edit my question. We are still using an id as primary key to identifiy our entries. The identifier is just an add on to use for the routing.

Comment: what is this used for ```\App\Http\Traits\UsesIdentifier``` ?

Comment: i think the ```id``` is added to hidden attribute somewhere inside the base class or the trait.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention, please see my edit.

Comment: please remove this ```public function getIncrementing()
    {
        return false;
    }``` from the trait of its not necessary

Comment: Please remove ```getIncrementing()``` and ```getKeyBy()``` methods. and if necessary, use this ```$incrementning = false``` and ```$keyBy = 'string'``` as in https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys
But I don't think that will be necessary as you are internally using ```id``` as primary key

Comment: id should not be in the fillable. it will work fine even when not in fillable @QamarRafhan

Comment: I removed the 'getIncrementing'-function and it seems to work. Thanks a lot!! Can you explain why  'getIncrementing' makes this problem? I don't understand..

Comment: in getIncrenmenting() you are returning false. so, it will not create id automatically by auto incrementting. so, causing the issue.